# How can I fix a 'Undefined control sequence' error in order to convert a JupyterNotebook to PDF?

Tags: pdf, latex, jupyter, amazon-sagemaker, nbconvert

---

Hello everyone,

since this is my first post here (even though not my first time, because I've spent hours reading some of your brilliant answers over time), I hope you guys will forgive me initial mistakes, when it comes to writing a proper post.

I have a problem when trying to convert a JupyterNotebook, that runs on AWS SageMaker to PDF using nbconvert.

I am using the following command via the terminal:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to pdf MyNotebook.ipynb
```

And instead of the notebook converting into a PDF, I'll end up with the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\AfterEndPreamble ->\AddToHook 
                               {begindocument/end}
l.158 \AfterEndPreamble
                       {%
? 
! Emergency stop.
\AfterEndPreamble ->\AddToHook 
                               {begindocument/end}
l.158 \AfterEndPreamble
                       {%
No pages of output.
```

Converting it to a .tex file, however, works without any problems.

Now I've spend the last hour, trying to solve this issue by searching the web and looking at similar problems, but for the first time I couldn't find any solution to my specific issue yet.

So I hope, some of you will be able to help me with it.

Appreciate it!

Comment: Can you access the intermediate .tex file?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I am able to create a .tex file using ```jupyter nbconvert --to latex MyNotebook.ipbny```, which works like a charm.

Comment: Does that tex file compile without errors?

Comment: @Abby Yes, no errors when compiling the Tex file.